# React router dom v6 history

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, browser-history

How can I get a full history of react-router dom V6? So if I have let's say 3 pages "home", "settings", "details" and I switch them back and forward I want to get an array of my movement like ["home","settings","home","details"]. I know its stored somewhere because if I use navigate(-2) I'll get page "settings". But how can I get this list?

Comment: Simply stated, you can't, *directly*. The browser isn't going to leak out a user's entire browser history to your app, it will only expose out the `history.length` property. You can implement and maintain your own in-app history stack though.

Comment: I don't need all browser history, I need just a history from my app, so only history which was handled by this specific router

Comment: RRDv6 doesn't directly expose the `history` object in most cases. If you don't need the data routers then you can use the `HistoryRouter` with a custom `history` object and you can maintain your own "history stack" in app state.